# Sharepoint Calculated column in list

Tags: sharepoint

I added a new calculated column A to a sharepoint list. This column A should be updated if the value of another column B changes and if column A is still empty! I struggle in implementing the "if column A is still empty" part of the formula.

Here is my formula:

```
=IF([Issue Status]="Active",Today)
```

Additionally I added a column called "Today" and deleted it again after entering the formula. That works!

Does anybody know who to implement the "still empty" part?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Does the Today portion of your formula still work for you?  I've found that the "Today column trick" doesn't quite work as you'd expect.  The calculation is not dynamic -- it's only made when the item is edited.  The Today column becomes, in effect, a "Modified Date" column.  I'm still searching for a workable dynamic Today function/column solution.

Comment: The fake Today column trick doesn't work. http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/

Answer (score 1):

You would use the ISBLANK() function. Tip of the hat to [Primo over at ObjectMix](http://objectmix.com/sharepoint/317409-moss-list-check-list-null-calculated-column-formula.html#post1135466).

Some [common functions available](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011609471033.aspx) are listed on the Office help site that may also help.

Essentially you'll end up with a formula along the lines of:

=IF(OR([Issue Stats]="Active",ISBLANK([B])), "true value", "false value")